# Future não é reconhecida no Flutter (Dart)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Estou estudando Flutter e recentemente tive um problema um tanto quanto chato. Estava usando o Future para minha programação assíncrona e fiz o código todo, tal qual o exemplo que estava vendo. Todavia, percebi que o Future não estava sendo reconhecido, e havia uma recomendação para que eu fizesse o `import` do pacote `async`. Fiz isso, porém mesmo assim o problema não resolveu.

```
Future<int> insertAgendamento(Agendamento agendamento) async {
    Database db = await this.database;

    var resultado = await db.insert(agendaTable, agendamento.toMap());

    return resultado;
}
```

Acontece que eu já fiz o `import` e coloquei uma dependência no `pubspec.yaml`.

```
import 'dart:async';
```

Quando passo o mouse por cima do meu "Future" aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> Future isn't a type.
> Try correcting the name to match an existing type.

E nesse `import`, aparece o aviso que eu não estou o utilizando... Talvez seja alguma coisa boba, que por falta de atenção, não consegui achar. Mas gostaria da ajuda de vocês.

Comment: Olá! Poderia **[edit]** a sua pergunta para incluir a mensagem de erro que você está recebendo? :)

Comment: Olá Luiz! Fiz a edição que você pediu. O erro que aparece, é no Visual Studio, quando passo o mouse por cima do Future.

Comment: Qual a versão do seu flutter e dart?

Comment: Leandro, minha versão do Flutter é (Channel stable, 1.22.6) eu a atualizei recentemente, pois achei que era esse o problema. Já a versão do Dart é SDK version: 2.10.5 (stable).

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema, o que eu precisei fazer foi configurar o meu `import` para ser chamado por Fut: `import 'dart:async' as Fut;`

Logo em seguida, fui até meu código e coloquei:

```
Fut.Future<int> insertAgendamento(Agendamento agendamento) async {
Database db = await this.database;

var resultado = await db.insert(agendaTable, agendamento.toMap());

return resultado;}
```

Após isso, meu problema foi resolvido.

Achei esta alternativa [nesta discussão](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28995) no github, cuja solução foi apresentada pelo usuário yringler.

Comment: Por mais que tenha 'funcionado', eu não consideraria isso como uma solução válida. Tem que funcionar sem precisar utilizar destes artifícios, limpe o cache, reinicie a IDE, verifique se vc não criou outra classe com o nome Future..

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Julio, fiz esses passos (limpar o cache e reiniciar a IDE) e resolveu.